# Read AppSettings.json data in user defined class in Asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to access the "BaseURL" key value in my user defined class instead of controller. Please help me how to do the same

Below is My AppSettings.json

```
{
    "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
        }
     },
    "BaseURL": "http://192.168.0.72/mehcrm/CMS/public/api/v1/"`
}
```

Need your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take "BaseURL" value in Startup.cs like mentioned in below code.

```
public class Startup
{

 public static string BaseUrl { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
          var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        BaseUrl = Configuration.GetSection("BaseURL").Value;
    }
 } 

    public static string GetBaseUrl()
    {
        return Startup.BaseUrl;
    }
```

Use it in other classes in the project like shown below:

```
string BaseUrl= Startup.GetBaseUrl();
```